# In Ext.net, I want to put a gridpanel inside a panel and refresh it programmatically

Tags: ext.net

In Ext.net, I want to put a gridpanel inside a panel and refresh it programmatically

Code:

```
<ext:TabPanel runat="server" Region="Center">
    <Items>
        <ext:Panel 
             runat="server" 
             Title="Center" 
             Border="false" 
             BodyPadding="6">                  
                 <Items>
                    <ext:GridPanel ID="GridPanel1" runat="server" Title="Array Grid" Width="500" Height="350" />
                 </Items>
        </ext:Panel>
     </Items>
</ext:TabPanel>
```

When I explore the page, its blank, when I remove the gridpanel, other stuff showe normally!

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: The code you have provided appears to be correct. If no `.Height` is set on the `<ext:GridPanel>`, try setting `Layout="fit"` on the `<ext:Panel>`.

Comment: Is there any JavaScript error?